# CSV file read fail (PHP )

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file (delimited by commas) but unfortunately, it isn't responding as it ought to. I am not so sure what I am doing wrong here, but I'll paste out the contents of the code and the CSV file both :

```
$row = 0;
if($handle = fopen("SampleQuizData.csv","r") !== FALSE)
{
    // WORKS UNTIL HERE, SO FILE IS BEING READ
    while(!feof(handle))
    {
        $line = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ",") ;
        echo $line[2];  // DOES NOT WORK
    }    
}
```

Here is the CSV file: (the emails and names have been changed here to protect the identities of the users)

```
parijat,something,parijatYkalia@hotmail.com
matthew,durp, mdurpdurp@gmail.com
steve,vai,stevevai@gmail.com
rajni,kanth,rajnikanth@superman.com
```

Comment: Can you echo $line[0]? What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: Please enable `error_reporting` before asking questions, and note that it would have told ya you are missing an `$` in `feof(handle)` (should be `feof($handle)`. _always_ enable _all_ errors while developing, or at least before asking here :P

Comment: I rectified it, and it's the same thing..the computer is stuck trying to parse the CSV file.

Comment: Have you tried using a `semi-colon` as the seperator, to see if you get/got a different result?

Comment: you mean replace all commas with semi-colons in my csv file and then use a semi-colon delimiter instead ?

Comment: Try it as a new test file, starting from scratch, then see what the results are. Leave your setup the way it is. The comma seperator may be at fault. Hard to say without your full code(s).

Comment: If you wish to address a certain user, use the `@` symbol followed by the person's name (no space between). That way "I" or another person you are answering, will be notified.

Comment: @Fred,  that is pretty much the full code, minus the <?php ?> tags. Just playing around with CSV files and tryin to get a hang on how to process them. I will go ahead and attempt what you are describing though

Comment: Make a `copy` of everything first, before you test. You will have to change any reference to a comma, to a semi-colon.

Comment: yea, it's just 4 lines of code anyways, everytime I do this my computer makes a huge sound like if it's trying to process a massive load....I did the semi colons and it is the same result...phew. :\

Comment: @user1020069 I posted an answer which worked for me, depending on the ouput you want, modify as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Give this a try:**

```
<?php

$row = 0;

if (($handle = fopen("SampleQuizData.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
{
    while(!feof($handle))
    {
        $line = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ",") ;
        echo "$line[2]";
    }    
}

?>
```

Comment: This worked for me. You can change the `$line[2]` to `$line[1]` etc.

Comment: that worked for me too...going to do a code difference and find out what went wrong ..thanks @Fred!

Comment: @user1020069 You're quite welcome. The code difference was missing extra parentheses on your 2nd line. Might be more, but that's what I can remember. Cheers~

Comment: yea that was this, did a diff...so that parentheses is required eh...not sure why...dumb question but a question regardless!

Comment: @user1020069 The only `dumb questions`, are the ones that are `not asked` ;-)

Comment: @user1020069 You may like to consult http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php it has many other examples you can use to lay it out differently. `See example #1 on page.`

Answer (score 2):

it lacks a '$' to the handle variable

```
while(!feof($handle)){
```

and not :

```
while(!feof(handle)){
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth a mention but when I was working on CSV exports a few weeks ago, I had weird line ending inconsistencies. So I put this at the top of my php file and it worked splendid.

```
<?php
    ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
?>
```